# Web Browser control error

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I made this simple web browser using win-forms

```
namespace WebBrowser
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();      
        // Load the user's home page.
        webBrowser1.GoHome();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
        textBox1.Text = webBrowser1.Url.ToString();
    }
    private void Navigate(String address)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(address)) return;
        if (address.Equals("about:blank")) return;
        if (!address.StartsWith("http://") &&
            !address.StartsWith("https://"))
        {
            address = "http://" + address;
        }
        try
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(address));
        }
        catch (System.UriFormatException)
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    private void backButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (webBrowser1.CanGoBack)
        {
            webBrowser1.GoBack();
        }
        else
            backButton.Enabled = false;
    }      
    private void forwardButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (webBrowser1.CanGoForward)
        {
            webBrowser1.GoForward();
        }
        else
            forwardButton.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.GoHome();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Stop();
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!webBrowser1.Url.Equals("about:blank"))
        {
            webBrowser1.Refresh();
        }
    }
}

    }
```

` ,everything works perfectly except the back and forward buttons. I've added event handlers for both. please point out the errors.I use visual studio 2010 ultimate.

Comment: Have u tried this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873632/adding-back-and-forward-button-for-webbrowser-control

Comment: not working means , it's not hitting the event handler or something else?

Comment: Using your code, I got forward and back to work fine. Put a break point in the handlers for forward and back. Do they get hit?

Comment: Thank you very much.I figured out that ide wasn't linking them with the event handlers because i had created 2 events for the same button and later removed the original one .So i added the event handlers in "form1.designer.cs" manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just added the event handlers for back and forward buttons in " form1.designer.cs " manually.They might get deleted by several reasons.